# running big query from python with encoded google authentication file

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have some very standard big query python code to execute some big query queries. I can set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and it works fine. The issue I have is the file is encoded in base64, of course running the below code with a credentials file which is encoded in base64 will cause an an exception to be thrown. Is there anyway to pass the json content as a string once decoded or otherwise to the below so that my query will run?

```
jobConfig = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
client = bigquery.Client()
queryJob = client.query("select * from my_table limit 10")
print(queryJob.result())
```

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant solution if you are in an environment in which you don't have access to a file system and you can't save credentials:

```
import base64, json
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account


key = json.loads(base64.b64decode(my_base64_key))
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(key)

client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=credentials.project_id)
```

Based on https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file#python

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find this [public reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file#bigquery-authentication-service-account-file-python) stating how to load a JSON content in order to properly run the above query:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(
'path/to/service_account.json')
```

Comment: I don't think this quite answers the question, because it sounds like there's a string var containing the credentials and not a file. Looking at the code for this method on GitHub, I can see how you would do it though.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not elegant but this workaround works for me:

```
import base64, json, os
from google.cloud import bigquery


tmp_key_location = 'tmp_key.json'
key = json.loads(base64.b64decode(my_base64_key))
with open(tmp_key_location, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(key, f)

client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(tmp_key_location)
os.remove(tmp_key_location)
```

Cleaner solutions are more than welcome but I work with what I have